# Add/Set a File to SharePoint List Item Attachment using Scripts

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want to Add (or) Set a file as an Attachment to a SharePoint List Item. Is there any possibility to do with JavaScript (or) ECMAScript (or) JQuery for this Query. Suggest me only the Script Solutions.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

It appears from this post that there is no script only way of adding attachments to list items. You may have to use the combination of script and webservices.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969810/sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-add-attachment-to-listitem